# Describing Pain during Movement

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, difference

What do you recommend me to choose between these two?

I believe they are both correct but I want to make sure and also to know which of them is more often used.

> **I have a pain in my leg** (or shoulder, eye, ear, etc) **when I walk** (move my hand, blink, listen to music).

or

> **My leg hurts when I walk**.

(This one sounds a bit strange for me, because I think it makes some actions and kicks somebody when I walk...)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My leg hurts when I walk.

This is a perfectly idiomatic and normal usage of English to say that it is uncomfortable for you to walk because your leg hurts, or just to draw attention to the fact that you were injured.

> (This sounds a bit strange for me, because I think it makes some actions and kicks somebody when I walk...)

I'm... not sure how you can infer that. I can't say this without sounding facetious, but English doesn't have a mind of its own, and I don't know of any secret cultural standards in the Anglosphere (English-speaking world) that would attach that implication to your sentence. If you didn't say that you kicked someone, then you aren't thought to have gotten in a fight simply because your leg was injured -- that would be a very spontaneous assumption, unless the person making the assumption is a licensed doctor and can tell just by looking that you were probably in a fight.

Comment: I think the "sounds strange" part is because of the verb _hurts_. If the O.P. is accustomed to _hurt_ being used as a transitive verb (_Melanie hurt Bob when she kicked him_, e.g.), then I can see where there might be some confusion.

Comment: :) Thank you for your answer. What can I say.., that's the feeling I have about this phrase and that's why I usually avoid to use it. I didn't talk about English. If it would have had a "me" after "hurts", I think that would have been more clearly. Now I understand that it is perfectly correct to say "My leg hurts when I walk." Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Ah, then @J.R. is correct. Many verbs can be used transitively and intransitively, and it is important to notice the difference because the meanings often change completely. In this case "My leg hurts me" implies that your leg is somehow fighting against your the rest of your body... but saying "My leg hurts" is the same as saying "my leg is causing me to feel pain" or "my leg is injured."